# How to show list of data from GET-request

Tags: reactjs, axios

Im trying to get the data from my server by clicking on the `Get studentData`.
As shown in the picture from the browser of the console, I'm getting the data but the data is not displayed in the browser.
[image: Browser image]

And this is my code for the get data component:

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios'

export default function Datateacher() {
  const [result, setResult] = useState([]);

  const handleClick = async () => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const result = await axios.get(`http://localhost:8000/state`, { mode: 'no-cors' });
      console.log(result.data)
      setResult(result.data)
    }
    fetchData();
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button type="button" onClick={handleClick} >
        Get studentdata
      </button>
      <ul>
        <h3>
          {result.map(results => results.data)}
        </h3>
      </ul>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to render `data` field which doesn't exist in your `result`.

Try something like this:

```
<h3>
 {
   result.map(item => item.id)
 }
</h3>
```

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of places that you need to improve to run your code,

1. You're not returning the data from your map function. You need to return the JSXElement from your `map`.
2. You are creating unnecessary method `fetchData`.

Here is your working code:

```js
import { useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios'

export default function Datateacher() {
  const [result, setResult] = useState([]);

  const handleClick = async () => {
    const result = await axios.get(`http://localhost:8000/state`, { mode: 'no-cors' });
    setResult(result.data)
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button type="button" onClick={handleClick} >
        Get studentdata
      </button>
      <ul>
        {result.map((result) => <h1>{result.data}</h1>)}
      </ul>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Couple of things are wrong in your provided code.

First of all, why your `fetchData()` function is located within the `handleClick()` one ?

You can remove your `handleClick()` function. It is not necessary because it's just used to call another function (`fetchData()`) in your case.

```
const fetchData = async () => {
  const result = await axios.get(`http://localhost:8000/state`, { mode: 'no-cors' });
  setResult(result.data) 
};
```

So, on your button click, you just call `fetchData()`.

Also, your state should be `[results, setResults]` as you are retrieving multiple items (readability is something important).

Then you map your elements like so :

```
results.map(result => result)
```

First you have a collection that you iterate over, then you have one item.

Last thing, you're trying to get a key named `data` in your result item which doesn't exist. Try `result.id` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting data as an array of student objects. If you want to display data then you need to parse the array and then the individual object properties.
For ex:
results.data[0].id this would display the id of first student object.

Answer (score 0):

You are not mapping through your `result` state correctly (there is no `data` field on your items). Find below an example for having the names of students displayed:

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

export default function Datateacher() {
  const [result, setResult] = useState([]);

  const handleClick = async () => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const result = await axios.get(`http://localhost:8000/state`, { mode: "no- cors" });

      console.log(result.data);
      setResult(result.data);
    };

    fetchData();
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button type="button" onClick={handleClick}>
        Get studentdata
      </button>
      <ul>
        <h3>
          {result.map((item) => (
            <p>{item.name}</p>
          ))}
        </h3>
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Im sorry about the bad code-post, because i cant clearly see fetchData() is totally unnecessary, it was because i used another method before.
But it is working now, it was the data property that gave problem, thanks!

Comment: This is not an answer but a comment